# java.util.Optional to java.lang.Iterable?

Tags: java, option-type

Is there a better alternative to writing a custom function? Preferably in the stock JDK?

If not, is there a better implementation than the following:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> toIterable(Optional<T> o) {
    if (o.isPresent()) {
        return Collections.singletonList(o.get());
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java 9 you can do `Iterable<T> iterable = () -> o.stream().iterator();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Optional.isPresent()` is usually code smell - it is no different from `!= null`.

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> toIterable(Optional<T> o) {
    return o.map(Collections::singleton)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptySet);
}
```

Also, a singleton `Set` is a better model for a ... well [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)).

Comment: Talking about singletons, `Collections.emptySet()` returns a singleton. There's not much point in using the supplier.

Comment: @shmosel fair point. Not sure it makes much difference however: `orElse(Collections.emptySet())` or `orElseGet(Collections::emptySet)`. Further, the JavaDoc says "_need not create a separate `Set`_" - returning the same `Set` is implementation specific.

Comment: You left out the next sentence. :)

Comment: Downvote because it's obsurd to say Optional.isPresent is no different from `!= null`. The first is type-safe and statically checked by the compiler.

Comment: @Blake eh? I honestly have no idea where you are coming from. `if(x != null)` and `Optional.ofNullable(x).ifPresent` are **identical**. The type inference in the latter means that there is no type safety whatsoever. You need to know what `x` is either way.

Comment: @BoristheSpider There is a difference. Using the former, you don't know whether for any variable x you need to use that (and hence risking NPE). The latter, though, you can assume every Optional needs to be checked except before it get's passed to another function.

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(x).ifPresent is an abomination imho.  The body is a lambda that has access only to final variables, while it exists only for its side effect.  A bit contradictory.  And exception handling becomes a problem.  The test is a couple of instructions in the JVM, the optional version involves a method call.